# special case of best first search algorithms

Tags: search-algorithms, search

I read somewhere that DFS is a special case of Best first search algorithm if f(n)=-depth(n). please justify this i am not getting it.:/

Answer (score 1):

Consider a node $u$ such that $depth(u)=l$.

In Best first Search when you evaluate $u$ with the evaluation function you defined, you have $f(u)=−l$.

```
queue

╔═══╤═══╤═════╤═══╗
║ r │ a │ ... │ u ║
╚═══╧═══╧═════╧═══╝
```

When you expand $u$ and you evaluate the first child of $u$ (suppose it is Node $v$) you have $f(v)=−(l+1)<−l=f(u)$ so now you expand $v$ (that means that you put $v$ in the front of the queue) and you continue.

```
queue

╔═══╤═══╤═════╤═══╤═══╗
║ r │ a │ ... │ u │ v ║
╚═══╧═══╧═════╧═══╧═══╝
```

This corresponds to what you do when you use Depth First Search.

Comment: is minus sign here showing the very first position of the queue? i.e the node with the least cost?